# System.out.println() always display class not value

Tags: java, tostring

how to display value of content in object in Java? I always get something like: **org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor@1a28aef12019-10-13**

```
@Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callback());
        System.out.print("toStringBean: "+securityInterceptor.toString());


        //Security Policy -> securityPolicy.xml
        return securityInterceptor;
    }
```

I read that I should use toString() but I get same result. I just need value of properties inside object :)

Comment: That is the default `toString()` of a Java object. You need to look at the documentation of [`XwsSecurityInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/xwss/XwsSecurityInterceptor.html) to find out how to get the information you want. Looking at that documentation, it doesn't really have a content, so you need to be more clear in describing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the properties of XwsSecurityInterceptor using toString method as it is not overridden in the class from Object class.If you want to see the value you better put a debug point in the class and inspect the values and run the application in Debug mode. 
For Debug in intellij.

click on the bug button in below screenshot. For adding the dubug point just single click on line number. then a red dot appears on the line number. When you run the application. You can see execution stops at the point. Then right click on the variable and select Evaluate Expression and a popup opens. Just click on the evaluate button in the popup and you can see the different value of objects present in the class.

[image]

Comment: which IDE - Eclipse/ Intellij/Net beans  you use?

Comment: I am using ide intellij